# React Native — Delay between toggling Switch and resulting conditional changes in View

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```js
import { Switch } from 'react-native';

export default function Screen() {
    const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
    const toggleSwitch = () => {
        console.log("test")
        setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState)
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Switch
              onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
              value={isEnabled}
            />
            {isEnabled ? (
                // View code here
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

There is View code which is conditional on `isEnabled`, which is set by the Switch. There is a delay between toggling the Switch, and this View code appearing / disappearing. There's also a slight delay between the `console.log("test")` printing, but less than the View stuff.

I've tried wrapping the `setIsEnabled` in `setImmediate(() => {`, `requestAnimationFrame(() => {`, but these have no effect.

Any thoughts on what I can do? I'm open to completely new solutions if that's appropriate — I just need a switch / toggle that affects the View.

Comment: Hey, it could be because the `// View code here` could be a heavy component, try it with simple `<Text>hello</Text>` and let me know if it's slow with just text too. Also, make sure the app is not in Debug mode.

Comment: Hey @RajRohitYadav, thanks for your message. It is indeed faster with just a simple Text, but there's still a noticeable delay compared with, for example, mui Switch in standard React.

Comment: I'm not sure how slow it is in your device, when you create a production build, UI will be faster, as there is a lot of overhead while development, UI is slower than what it will be in production. 

If even after the prod build the performance does not improve, you can try `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-switch` or any other 3rd party library. I haven't faced performance issues with switch in React Native. 

Also, comparing RN in development mode with the web is not fair 